# Redirect all requests to a subdomain except the root URL and index page under nginx

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, nginx

Up until now, our website consisted of a wiki with several wiki sites. We now decided to host some general information on a single page and move the wiki to a subdomain (`https://wiki.example.com/`). I want to redirect *nearly all* requests from `https://example.com/XYZ` to `https://wiki.example.com/XYZ`, only requests to `https://example.com/` and `https://example.com/index.php` should not be redirected.

The idea here is that people who have bookmarks to `https://example.com/FOO` get redirected to the correct page at `https://wiki.example.com/FOO` as well as people who come from search engines.

How can I achieve this with nginx?

Comment: I'm confused. You want to redirect a _all_ requests from `example.com/` to `wiki.example.com/` but you also say "only requests to `example.com/` and `example.com/index.php` should *not* be redirected? Can you please describe the desired experience from a user's perspective? If this is wordpress, what you describe breaks `wp-admin/` what about static assets? css, js, jpg/png/gif.

Comment: I tried to add some more information. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: only 301 for each individual page. remember, that https://example.com/index.php can generate https://example.com/index.php/foo and https://example.com/index.php/foo/bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to remove all the files from your document root except for `index.php` and remove all wiki configuration from your ngnix configuration for `example.com`.  Then `https://example.com/` and `https://example.com/index.php` will return the correct page and all other requests will return a 404 error.

Then you can set your 404 handler to do the redirect:

```
error_page 404 =301 http://wiki.example.com$request_uri;
```

Tested on Nginx 1.18.0

Source: [Module ngx_http_core_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Answer (score -2):

In the .htacess file in public_html of https://example.com/ write:

```
Redirect 301 /XYZ https://wiki.example.com/XYZ
```

It should do what you need

Comment: This doesn't appear to apply to nginx, and I believe it misunderstands the redirect situation.

Comment: nginx doesn't have .htacccess files, only Apache has those.